# can gparted (safely) extend partition size to space in front of root partition?

Tags: gparted

My root partition is getting to full, so I want to increase it's size. I know gparted can extend partition space with free space after a partition. However I only have available space in front of my partition. like this:

```
[available space][root][other partition]
```

Is it possible/safe to extend root with the available space in front of it?

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't find the answer to this question on here. So I decided just to try it and answer my own question.

**Is it safe?**

I don't know. messing with `/` doesn't feel safe. So make sure you **make a backup** just in case.

**Is it possible?**

yes it is. It worked fine for me. I used the instructions on [gparted.org](https://gparted.org/liveusb.php#linux-setup) to create a live usb. Booted from it. Removed my swap and then extended `/` to the space in front of it.

The only thing I forgot was to remove the line containing my swap UUID from `/etc/fstab` which caused some booting issues. Luckily I decided to ponder for a moment about possible causes before reinstalling an OS over my root partition. Maybe it is smart to do this step **before you use gparted**.

```bsh
# comment out/remove this line
# UUID=<MY_UUID> swap           swap    defaults,noatime 0 2
```